# Me da un resultado erroneo al hacer operaciones

Tags: c

Hola buenas a la hora de que mi programa me de los resultado de Perimetro y Area , me dan resultados erroneos y no entiendo muy bien porque me da esos resultados os dejo el codigo por si encontrais vosotros algun error . Muchas gracias

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

float main(){
    float A,B,C,Area,S,P;
    int tipoError=0;
printf("Escribe el lado a:");
scanf("%f",&A);
printf("Escribe el lado b:");   /*Declaro las variables que se van a usar*/
scanf("%f",&B);
if(A<B){
    tipoError=2;
    printf("Ha ocurrido el error %i \n",tipoError); /*Hago varios condicionales para los distintos errores*/
    return 0;
}
printf("Escribe el lado c:");
scanf("%f",&C);
if(A<C){
    tipoError=4;
    printf("Ha ocurrido el error %i\n",tipoError);
    return 0;
}
if(A>B+C){
    tipoError=1;
    printf("Ha ocurrido el error %i\n",tipoError);
    return 0;
}
if(tipoError==0){
    printf("Todos los datos son correctos\n");
    printf("Lado a=%f Lado b=%f Lado c=%f \n",A,B,C); /*Si no hay ningun error el programa hara las operaciones*/
    P=A+B+C;                                          /* y finalizara pero no se porque no me hace bien la operacion*/
    S=P/2;
    S=S*(S-A)*(S-B)*(S-C);
    Area=sqrt(S);
    printf("Perimetro: %f Area: %f"),P,Area;

}
}
```

Comment: Deberías poner ejemplos de los resultados erróneos que te da.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Está fallando porque cerraste antes el paréntesis:

```
printf("Perimetro: %f Area: %f"),P,Area;
```

Debería ser:

```
printf("Perimetro: %f Area: %f", P, Area);
```

Puedes probarlo [aquí](https://tio.run/##rVPBbptAEL3zFSMqV5jgkjbpJQ6RwI2UQw6W6LGXYVnslWCXzEKltMqv153dYFuJFSmHcECzs8N7b94MYrERYrf7pLRox1rCtR1qZb5sb4JjqsNh6zJB0xocoEOlo/nfAPh5zuRJkaySnCQmZbJe@hulBxhUb26JDGXny6AnTjVReGsFqUqCbKHF2gBehfNlYAVqvpw1YfI5n79dXblqhk/jH1K0SIbTFn4jKaxaaeFhlGAlJzQgjBYpTl9gF4ytmii/LqYOjhq/PQvfM98hGDESKWZldulqYKbglw6Tw0esJY3vcGO8BGNBGF0roYxGp6ZHQmg5XSs7MCxHHkdaluXISA4jaWB7nt5sWZwYtNo3sTpp4vJdTbzq4USKA78pzk7hv34U/BEyO59Y9qA/Tc0@edfQOWaNZluJpOATQ89farj3S5TNGvBRdYiEi5wUv55@UqUCbWCLj6CV3ox6UszSezIbwg750o2Md8r0ktBN8jCsdZafsSlu/d75pDE8QqN4GdQfh8uQxingDe0NuV3lQyeZVEiolNTMfCSeaMtsnU67WWZlHJWLfO7ehX@vJjvc35fZBxqi8pVBa0mqkwOZK2BDXJ0LwmTt/1gu5ok87Xbfg8vg4p9oWtzY3aLt/gM).

---

Si el compilador (gcc) no encuentra la función `sqrt` como me pasó a mí, debes agregar el parámetro `-lm`.

Por cierto, no crees que sería buena idea devolver `tipoError` como código de salida de tu programa? Con:

```
return tipoError;
```